# Excel viewer in SharePoint 2010 not loading Workbook

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2010, web

I have added a .xlsx file to a shared documents folder in sharepoint 2010. When I click it the xlviewer.xls is loaded but it just continually shows the loading animation. I can load the file in Excel using the Edit in Microsoft Excel' option.The same happens if I use a 'Excess Web Access' web part, it just shows loading.

I am new to sharepoint and wonder if I have a setting not turned on properly.

TIm

EDIT:

here is a section from my log file

> 12/02/2011 17:00:09.70    w3wp.exe (0x1564)                           0x1710  Excel Services Application      Excel Calculation Services      2026    Warning     An internal error occurred.    at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.MossHost.MossHost.Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.Host.IEwaHost.IsSecureConnection()     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.EwaCUIDataSource.EnsureDocument()     at Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.CUIDataSource.RunQuery(UIQuery query)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.EwaRibbon.QueryRibbonDataSource(CultureInfo uiCulture, String clientID, Boolean denormalizeImareUri)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.EwaStringsHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    3ed6a78e-e010-4fe9-bf93-14b56938ed65
>   12/02/2011 17:00:09.77  w3wp.exe (0x1564)                           0x1710  Excel Services Application      Browser                         f2n9    Exception   EwaStringsHandler.ProcessRequest: An unexpected exception occured. Rethrowing an HttpException so that the response is not cached by the browser. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.MossHost.MossHost.Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.Host.IEwaHost.IsSecureConnection()     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.EwaCUIDataSource.EnsureDocument()     at Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.CUIDataSource.RunQuery(UIQuery query)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.EwaRibbon.QueryRibbonDataSource(CultureInfo uiCulture, String clientID, Boolean denormalizeImareUri)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.EwaStringsHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    3ed6a78e-e010-4fe9-bf93-14b56938ed65
>   12/02/2011 17:00:09.77  w3wp.exe (0x1564)                           0x1710  SharePoint Server               Unified Logging Service         c91s    Monitorable Watson bucket parameters: SharePoint Server 2010, ULSException14, 5f9be61a "excel services application", 0e00129b "14.0.4763.0", f5b5c9d6 "microsoft.office.excel.server.mosshost", 0e001785 "14.0.6021.0", 4d65e5e7 "thu feb 24 05:00:23 2011", 000002d3 "000002d3", MISSING, 4a6d3421 "nullreferenceexception", 66326e39 "f2n9"   3ed6a78e-e010-4fe9-bf93-14b56938ed65
>   12/02/2011 17:00:09.95  w3wp.exe (0x1564)                           0x1710  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.Web.HttpException: Internal error    at Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.EwaStringsHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)    3ed6a78e-e010-4fe9-bf93-14b56938ed65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/f8fdf03e-cf15-4e2d-985c-e88598f4580e

I had to creatre an empty site collection at the root of my server e.g. http:\sharepoint\

Answer (score 1):

Have you confirmed with your Sharepoint Admin that Excel Web Services has been enabled?

Comment: Web services are enabled. I am running in a developer environment not the main server. I have enabled logging on the excel services will check for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. You have to create a SiteCollection Root in the WebApp whose xlsx been loaded. There´s no need to be a blank one.

Also, its been solved in October, 2011 CU: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2596582